# AsyncCrudAppService Breaks Swagger When Providing TCreateInput and TUpdateInput

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I recently downloaded a Single Page Web Application (Angular) from https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates using 3.x target version.

I just simply added a few entities and then started to follow the steps on this page https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Application-Services

Things do work well for me to Get, List, Update, and Delete entities when my app service class is just inheriting AsyncCrudAppService<Entities.PhoneBook, PhoneBookDto, long, GetAllPhoneBooksInput>, however when it is inheriting AsyncCrudAppService<Entities.PhoneBook, PhoneBookDto, long, GetAllPhoneBooksInput, CreatePhoneBookInput, and UpdatePhoneBookInput> the swagger definition will no longer load.

GitHub Repo: https://github.com/woodman231/MyPhoneBooks

(which currently does not work and will not load Swagger page).

I can get the swagger page to load by removing CreatePhoneBookInput and UpdatePhoneBookInput from

https://github.com/woodman231/MyPhoneBooks/blob/main/aspnet-core/src/MyPhoneBooks.Application/SimpleCrudAppServices/ISimplePhoneBookCrudAppService.cs#L9

and

https://github.com/woodman231/MyPhoneBooks/blob/main/aspnet-core/src/MyPhoneBooks.Application/SimpleCrudAppServices/SimplePhoneBookCrudAppService.cs#L14

However, again I am still unable to create entities using this default implementation. Any ideas?

Comment: Please check the log in MyPhoneBooks.Web.Host/App_Data/Logs.txt, when this happens the application logs what is happening,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have cloned your repo and run it and I figured out the error, first as I tell you in comments I verified the text log, and it said the next:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Can't use schemaId "$CreatePhoneBookInput" for type "$MyPhoneBooks.SimpleCrudAppServices.Dtos.CreatePhoneBookInput". The same schemaId is already used for type "$MyPhoneBooks.PhoneBooks.Dtos.CreatePhoneBookInput"

What happenig is that you have these two classes `UpdatePhoneBookInput`, `CreatePhoneBookInput` repeated in `SanokeCrudAppServices\Dtos` and `PhoneBooks\Dtos`

You have the classes in both folders with same exact name, and thats the problem, if you change the name in whatever place the swagger definition will load without errors, I have do it like this and everything works fine!

Change the name in one of the places, and all will be working fine

Personally I don't like to use a different `Dto` for `Create` and `Update` for me is easier to user just one `Dto` for all.

Comment: Yep that certainly worked for me. Out of curiosity where did you get the text log. I checked the bin folder and couldn't see it. Plus in the AbpAuditLog table didn't have that either.

Comment: You can find the log file in MyPhoneBooks.Web.Host/App_Data/Logs.txt, please make the answer as resolved plase!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. I had also made a DIY AppService and some of the DTO Class Names associated with the DIY App Service clashed with the DTO Class Names associated with the Automated Service. It was acceptable in .NET since they were in different name spaces but once the swagger definition was configured I assume that there was multiple instances of the same DTO Defition. I checked the AbpLogs table but they didn't give me much details as to the specifics of the internal server error while loading the definition. It sure would have been useful to know that.